# Extracting a specific variable in a script tag on a webpage with multiple script tags with Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to build a simple javascript web scrapping project which extracts headlines from some news website.

the page I'm trying to scrape:

https://www.chinatimes.com/?chdtv

It has over 30 script tags

The variable I wanted to access is data on line 1610 in view-source mode(as shown below), which contains all the headline titles and URLs(unfortunately, they are available only here)

```
<script type="c04ba886ffa04b8e214f17e6-text/javascript">
        //速報
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".breaking-news").verticalMarquee({
                "onContentHeightChanged": function (baseDiv, contentHeight) {
                    var $self = $(baseDiv),
                        contentPadding = 12;
                    $self.height(contentHeight + contentPadding);
                }
            });
        });
        //焦點大圖
         $(document).ready(function () {
            var photoUrl;
var data = [...];
...
</script>
```

I tried targeting the script tag with puppeteer using `$eval` + css attribute selector, but the value of type for each scripts are dynamic(constantly changing)

Any solutions, opinions, keywords to google for will be deeply appreciated

Comment: Use some string manipulation on the HTML. Use some `substring` and `indexOf` , and take text from `var photoUrl` until `function`. Funny enough you can evaluate it to get the values you need.

Comment: What data are you ultimately trying to get?

Comment: @ggorlen The variable data in the code block I provided is a string of objects (which is too long so I did not include in the code), each object contains the titles, URLs, imgs of the headlines of this news websites, so I'm trying to extract them